# No Keyboard Output from Guard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, guard

When entering into debugger (byebug) with guard-minitest, I am unable to see the output while I am typing. I have seen this problem with Rails 4.2.8 as well as Rails 5.

If I run the test outside of guard, the debugger works fine.

```
byebug (9.0.6)
guard (2.14.1)
guard-minitest (2.4.6)
rails (4.2.8)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do you have `rb-readline` gem installed?

In my case removing it from `Gemfile` solved this issue!